# Does Steam back up my games?

Tags: steam

My laptop has been running pretty slow recently I am trying to fix bugs, and get rid of viruses and I might reset my laptop to start new. Before I do this I wanted to know if my games I bought are saved on Steam, so I can just re-download steam and get all my games back?

Comment: That is one of the key value adds of Steam... (there's also the steam cloud where save games can be saved).

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/can-i-safely-uninstall-games-purchased-from-steam?rq=1 + http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them?rq=1 + http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121341/do-i-have-to-pay-again-for-a-game-i-bought-on-a-different-pc-with-the-same-steam?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Every games you bought on Steam  will stay on your Steam account. Games are not linked to your computer, but your Steam account. You can even install your games on multiple computers and play them without any problems. You just need to log in.

The only thing that is not being backed up in all cases are your save files. Some games are using Steam Cloud, so those games are safe, but not every games. Look through your games to see which one use Steam Cloud and backup the saves of those who doesnt.